# When your executable behaves differently when invoked with ./

Tags: c, symbols

I just compiled some (parallelised) code in C, and have found the bewildering issue that it runs fine if invoked with

```
./executable
```

and when I try to run it "normally", i.e.

```
executable
```

I started hitting the error message:

```
unrecognised symbol: ompi_mpi_int
```

The message was the same one I had received before recompiling the executable (I had scp'ed it across from an older machine, and was recompiling it for use on the new cluster)

Why does my code run differently when invoked with "/." and without?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the specific error messages you get.

Comment: Is this on Linux? Then it's perfectly normal.

Comment: You have two different issues, and should ask two different questions.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, guys, for all the incredibly-fast assistance! I have edited to include the specific message, as suggested by @Ismail_Badawi. I guess it is similar to the question about the "./" as discussed above, but not quite the same, in that the error message is different :-) And, weirdly, I haven't hit this issue on Linux when something is on the path, before.

Comment: It's not at all a duplicate of that question. Voted to reopen...

Comment: Yay! Thanks, @Ismail_Badawi...

Comment: What are the output for `which executable` and `whereis executable`?

Comment: Oh, my! Thanks SO much, @cpatricio! You just made my day. I will edit the question right now to incorporate that...the output tells me it is in totally a different place to where I thought it was!

Comment: Yay! Now that I have done that, it WORKS!!! I honestly can't thank you enough, @cpatricio! If there was an option, I would say "+n", where n tends to infinity

Comment: I wish I could post the answer, but, since it's marked as a duplicate, I'll have to post it under that question...